# ¿Cómo puedo agregar una restricción de edades a mi programa?

Tags: c

Este programa ya es funcional, ya que si me da la instrucción principal, la cual es promediar todos las edades de los alumnos del grupo 8292, pero no se exactamente como aumentar una restricción, la cual es que solo se puedan poner edades de 18 a 40 años, y si no entra en ese espacio de números, que el programa te diga que no puede ser esas edades y lo tengas que hacer de nuevo.

```
/*Elabora un programa en lenguaje C para calcular el promedio de la edad de los alumnos del grupo 8292.
 El programa deberá solicitar la edad de cada alumno. La edad válida estará entre 18 y 40 años.
 El programa termina de pedir edades cuando la edad es 0 y debe mostrar la suma de las edades, el número de alumnos y el promedio.*/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (void)
{
    int i, n;
    float edad, promedio;
    promedio = 0;
    printf ("Ingrese el numero de estudiantes del grupo 8292: ");
    scanf ("%d", &n);
    (void) getchar ();
    for (i=1; i<=n; i++)
    {
        printf ("Estudiante %d\n", i);
        printf ("Ingrese la edad del estudiante: ");
        scanf ("%f", &edad);
        (void) getchar ();
        promedio=promedio+edad;
        putchar ('\n');

    }
    if (n == 0)
    {
        edad = 0;

    }

    else
    {
        promedio=promedio/n;
    }

    printf ("El promedio de edades del grupo 8292 es: %f\n", promedio);
    system ("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Esta pregunta es expresamente para C. Por eso eliminé la etiqueta de C++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> > ¿Cómo puedo agregar una restricción de edades a mi programa?

Simplemente hay que agregar un bucle (un `do-while` por ejemplo) en la cual hará iteraciones cuando la condición: `edad < 12 || edad > 40` se cumpla, de este modo, podremos validar que el usuario solo podrá ingresar una edad con el rango establecido por el programa.

El código quedaría así:

```c
int main (void)
{
    int i, n, exit;
    float edad, promedio;
    promedio = 0;
    printf ("Ingrese el numero de estudiantes del grupo 8292: ");
    scanf ("%d", &n);
    getchar ();
    for (i=1; i<=n; i++)
    {
        do
        {
            printf ("Estudiante %d\n", i);
            printf ("Ingrese la edad del estudiante: ");
            scanf ("%f", &edad);
            exit = (edad < 18 || edad > 40);
            if(exit) //Esto es equivalente a if(exit != 0)
                printf("\nError: La edad debe estar en el rango de 18 a 40 anios!\n");
        }while(exit);//Equivalente a exit != 0
        getchar ();
        promedio=promedio+edad;
        putchar('\n');
    }
    if (n == 0)
        edad = 0;
    else
        promedio=promedio/n;
    printf ("El promedio de edades del grupo 8292 es: %f\n", promedio);
    system ("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

**Explicación breve:**

Cuando esta condición se cumpla:

```c
exit = (edad < 18 || edad > 40);
```

La variable `exit` valdrá `1` y se enviará un mensaje de error al usuario y la condición del `do-while` será verdadera y con esto logramos que el usuario vuelva a ingresar la edad.

Si la variable `exit` vale `0` es porque el usuario ingresó una edad que está en el rango de `18` a `40` años.

**Nota:** La expresión `(void)` que está a lado de la función `getchar()` es innecesario, así que la puedes eliminar.

Comment: Efectivamente si se puede de esta manera, pero se entra en un bucle infinito en la que el número de estudiante siempre sera 1 y seguirá contando no importa la edad que pongas.

Comment: @JulioC. El código no genera un bucle infinito. Lo acabé de probar y funciona correctamente. El bucle `do-while` tiene una condición de salida y será `false` cuando `exit` tenga guardado un `0`. ¿Cuando `exit` valdrá `0`? Pues cuando esta condición: `èdad < 12 || edad > 40` no se cumpla. El objetivo de este código es mandar un mensaje de error al usuario y pedirle que vuelva a introducir la edad, debido a que, debe cumplir con la restricción dada (no se puede pasar del rango de `12` a `40`).

Comment: Una disculpa, tenía mi contador igual a 0, el cual no vi que era 1, es por eso que me daba el bucle infinito, te lo agradezco mucho!